# How to know the percentage of features that represent a classification in a vector layer

Tags: qgis, vector, classification, vector-grid, vector-layer

I have a classified vector grid layer [image] with five classes [image]

And I want to know what percentage each class represents of the whole vector layer.

I'm currently selecting the cells from each class multiplying by 100 and then dividing by the total number of cells in the grid, is there a faster way of calculating the percentages?

Comment: right-click on the classes and select feature count gives you the absolute number for each class, but unfortunately no percentage values. this part has to be done manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using field calculator to speed up the manually process of calculating your field, plus you can have a new field that has all of your percentages, then you could summarize the totals within that field whenever you need to access the totals. This is a good [overview](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html) from the QGIS documentation of using the field calculator.